# MySQL Select distinct values from 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table wich has links in it. So amongst others, there are 2 columns that contain URLs; Source and Destination. 
I need to get a list of all the unique urls that are present in the table (to create a lookup table), but a url can be in both columns of course. Using distinct on the 2 columns seems to return unique combinations, rather than single values. Can I do this in 1 query or should I use 2 (one for each column) and then a 3d distinct select on that result?

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: I think you need to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Follow up question: when I have the look up table, how do I get the unique combinations of these values that are present in the 1st table?

So basically the ID's from the look up table for the Distinct query on the 2 columns...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `UNION`, which will remove the duplicates (while `UNION ALL` will keep the duplicates)

```
SELECT FirstUrlColumn AS url
FROM myTable
UNION
SELECT secondUrlColumn AS url
FROM myTable
```

Comment: Any suggestion on a way to check the output? It is giving me the exact same number of rows as the distinct query for the 2nd column. This could be correct of course, but like to be sure.

Comment: Well, if you don't trust your RDBMS, this is a problem ;) You can check manually on a small part of your data, but, UNION does... what it has to do ! Maybe show your query if you select more fields than just url.

Comment: @Chrisvdberge you may try with an UNION ALL and see if you find differences, but...

Comment: thx.. I trust it does what I need it to do ;) 
Any suggestion on the follow up question; how to get the unique combinations from the 1st table using the ID's of the second? I guess this will be a Inner Join?

Comment: @Chrisvdberge your follow up is not that clear. Can you elaborate or ask a new question  please ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url
FROM (
    SELECT col1 AS url
    FROM TABLE
    UNION
    SELECT col2 AS url
    FROM TABLE
) urls
```

Comment: no need to select distinct on the union query. Union will remove the duplicates !