# find unique value from table in php

Tags: php, unique, distinct

I have a MySQL table which contains the following type of information:

```
hop_id  hop_1    hop_2    hop_3    hop_4..... hop_9  site_name  hop_count
1       abc>aaa  bcd>bbb  zxc>ccc                    GPAC       3
2       bcd>bbb  jkl>ddd  abc>aaa  pop>zoz           SNKL       4
3       jkl>ddd  zxc>ccc                             PBCL       2
```

I want to find unique value from hop_1, hop_2, hop_3....hop_9 & print them. The result will be like this.

```
hop       
abc>aaa
bcd>bbb
zxc>ccc
jkl>ddd 
pop>zoz
```

I use distinct keyword, but it works for one column, not for all columns. I want to print as one variable. please help how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436458/mysql-select-distinct-values-from-2-columns

Comment: ...and your PHP question is what exactly? BTW: Why did you create a table (hop_X) within a table? That's the first fault that makes this thing more difficult. If you had a table with site name and hops, you could solve this easily! You wouldn't waste memory if there are no hops either and you could extend this to more than nine hops as well without DB structure changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT(x.keyword) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT hop_1 as keyword FROM your table
 UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT hop_2 as keyword FROM your table
 UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT hop_3 as keyword FROM your table
....
SELECT DISTINCT hop_9 as keyword FROM your table) as x
```

Comment: how to print the result from this query? I gives me this error..."Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: i need to se more code i think mysqli query it's ok , so the problem should be in another place.
Try to execute this query on a mysql admin and see if it works.
This will return you the distinct values just like you asked.

1 value per row

Comment: @Caius I think my edit was wrong. Since you are using group by with keyword ,  is it necessary  to use  "SELECT DISTINCT(keyword)" ?

Comment: @jophab that's right , didn't realise about , but i'll edit it now.

Comment: thank u @Caius. It helped me a lot. Can u plz tell me, if I want to pick the site_name from the 1st table with this query, what would be that query? I use site_name before DISTINCT(x.keyword) but its show me error.

Comment: @sharvanaz `SELECT DISTINCT(x.keyword),x.site_name as site_name FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT hop_1 as keyword,site_name as site_name FROM your table
 UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT hop_2 as keyword,site_name as site_name FROM your table
 UNION SELECT DISTINCT hop_3 as keyword,site_name as site_name FROM your table
....
SELECT DISTINCT hop_9 as keyword,site_name as site_name FROM your table) as x `

Comment: wow.. great.
can you help me to solve this problem @Caius
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523329/how-to-find-necessary-values-of-a-unique-variable-from-two-table

Comment: @sharvanaz sure , just now i'll go to eat ;) .
When i come back i'll look what is about ;)

Comment: aww... that's so kind of you... :D sure, take your time. When you'll be free, please look at the problem & help me to solve this. :)