# how to find necessary values of a unique variable from two table

Tags: php, mysql, unique

1) I have a table named "plan_info_upload" which is like:

```
site_id site_name   2G_bw   3G_bw   route_path
1       MBCGP1      11      30      MBLMA1>MBSMGR
2       BOPBG2      12      22      BOPBG2>BOBET16
3       BOPCB1      11      0       BOBET16>BOGBT1>BOPBG2>BOBET16
4       BOSBB1      14      25      BOSBB1>BOKDG1>BOBET16>BOGBT1
```

2) & another table named "hop_without_router" which is like: (divide route_path from 1st table into hop)

```
hop_id  hop_1          hop_2         hop_3..... hop_9    site_name  hop_count
1      MBLMA1>MBSMGR                                     MBCGP1       1
2      BOPBG2>BOBET16                                    BOPBG2       1
3      BOBET16>BOGBT1 BOGBT1>BOPBG2  BOPBG2>BOBET16      BOPCB1       3      
4      BOSBB1>BOKDG1  BOKDG1>BOBET16 BOBET16>BOGBT1      BOSBB1       3
```

3) I find unique_hop from the 2nd table. the query is...

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT (hops.hop_route) FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_1 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router
                 UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_2 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router
                 UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_3 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router
                 UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_4 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router
                 UNION 
                ......
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_9 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router) as hops";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
       $hop_route = $row['hop_route'];
       echo $hop_route;
    }
}
```

result is like:

```
serial_id   unique_hop
1           MBLMA1>MBSMGR
2           BOPBG2>BOBET16
3           BOBET16>BOGBT1
4           BOGBT1>BOPBG2
5           BOSBB1>BOKDG1
6           BOKDG1>BOBET16
```

4) Now I have find how how many 2G_bw & 3G_bw each hop has & their total bandwidth. The result will be like this.

```
unique_hop     no_of_2G   no_of_3G   total_2G_bw   total_3G_bw
MBLMA1>MBSMGR   1          1          11           30
BOPBG2>BOBET16  2          2          23           52
BOBET16>BOGBT1  2          2          25           55
BOGBT1>BOPBG2   1          0          11           0
BOSBB1>BOKDG1   1          1          14           25
BOKDG1>BOBET16  1          1          14           25
```

I complete 3rd step. But can not match or complete the 4th step. How to complete 4th step using the tables? Please please can someone help me to complete this. Thanks in advance.

**One unique hop may have more than one site_name. & there is possible that one hop does not have any 3g bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this

```
SELECT hops.hop_route,count(plan_info_upload.*) as no_of_2G, SUM(plan_info_upload.2G_bw) as total_2G_bw FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT (hops.hop_route) as hop_route FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_1 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router
                 UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_2 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router
                 UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_3 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router
                 UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_4 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router
                 UNION 
                ......
                SELECT DISTINCT hop_9 as hop_route FROM hop_without_router) as hops ) as unique_hops )  LEFT JOIN plan_info_upload ON hops.hop_route = plan_info_upload.route_path
```

Comment: how can I find no_of_3G & total_3G_bw???
& this query give me error in saying "Trying to get property of non-object"... :(

Comment: you just have to add it behind 3g just like 3g is made, a count for total and sum for gentting the sum of all results.
Try exec this query dirrectly on your mysql (mysqlyog , navicat,phpmyadmin,etc) and tell me what error gives you there